# Is there still no way to delete and rename files in Libre Office?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, libreoffice

How can I delete or rename files from Libre Office open dialogue box?

Comment: Not going to be solved by AskUbuntu. The correct procedure would be to file a bug against libre office (or the open dialogue specifcally).

Comment: Same goes for Shutter, Workbench. It is by design.

Comment: @Rinzwind: It works flawlessly with Windows, hence the problem is Ubuntuspecific.

Comment: I'm not sure. If it works on Windows the Libre Office folks might just relaying Ubuntus (in that case deficient) file opening dialogue.

Comment: @empedokles see my 1st and 2nd comment. To reference those people that designed Windows as how it should be done in Linux is 1 bridge too far for me. The same stance can be reversed: Windows is wrong. A "open" dialogue should "open" a file and not let you delete it. Deleting files is a file managers task. Windows opening a file manager could be considered a design flaw, and not a design feature ;)

Comment: This guy is asking about running a third - party application in Ubuntu. It should not be closed.

Comment: @Muzaffar nope. The file dialogue it not LO. It is LightDM. Besides that he is asking for a design feature change. Those should be files as a bug against the file dialogue. we cant fix this for him

Comment: @Rinzwind But then, what you call a design flaw saves me the time to start another application just to open up the same directory I'm currently in during my daily work. The file opening dialogue is the only place where I can spot old documents "during" my workroutine, without interrupting it. So it makes sense to spot and delete old files in an opening dialogue. Especially with in a word editor where about 40 letters get created daily.

Comment: @Rinzwind: It's coming with the basic Ubuntu I use. You are cherry picking there.

Comment: @empedokles is there a reason you could not use the file manager ? You could even leave it open throughout the day unlike the open dialog.

Comment: @NGRhodes I would have to interrupt my work routing and decidedly would have to choose to spend hours on deleting old files. On the other hand I see the old files right away if I open another file.

Comment: Check my updated answer below, I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: It may come from basic ubuntu, but it still isn't ubuntu. Same as firefox isn't ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

In Libre Writer from the menubar go to:

**Tools - Options - Libre Office -General**

and mark the "*Use Libre Office Dialogue Boxes*":

[image]

Now you may delete or rename files withing the open dialogue box!

**There is another way to delete files without changing default options** (for Unity desktop):

1. In Libre Office Writer go to File - Open (Ctrl + O):

[image]

2. Drag the file you want delete and drop it to the "Trash" icon on the lower left corner.

[image]

**Edit: If you are using Gnome, you will have to customize your desktop a bit for this.**

1. Install gnome-tweak-tool

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Enable "Show Trash on the desktop" option within Gnome tweak tools.
3. Resize Libre Open dialog, i.e make it smaller so that it will allow you to see that Trash icon.

Comment: That requires you are using Unity - which I'm not so it doesn't work for me.  And it isn't deleting from within Libre Office...

Comment: He is asking about file opening dialog - not deleting from Libre. In Gnome you have to enable show Trash icon from Gnome tweak tools for this and resize Libre office dialog.

Comment: I have no dock, so I can't see how that will hep... And he is asking about deleting from the Libre file open dialogue...

Comment: @Mzaffar: I'm using Gnome.

Comment: @Muzaffar: Thanks, renaming works. Deleting not.

Comment: Deleting works for me. But it is deleting without sending it to trash, i.e. deleting it permanently.

Answer (score 1):

#### No there isn't. Why?

Libre Office is just that - it's a free Office Suite. So the basic requirements:

- Create new files
- Open files
- Edit files
- Save files
- Close files

The formatting, image / table inserting, text colour are all side effects of the "Edit files" requirement.

So why don't they enable deleting / renaming files? It doesn't come under the categories:

- Open files - You don't need to change the name of a file to open it. And you don't want to delete that file.
- Edit files - You don't want to delete the file - maybe renaming would make sense.
- Save files - You don't want to delete the file, and you can use "Save As" to rename.

#### It is very inconvenient. Is it?

I can see why you would say that - the open dialogue and the file manager look very similar:

[image] [image]

But they do very, very different functions - one if for managing files. The other is for accessing one type of file - opening it.

#### Is there a workaround? Sort of.

I wouldn't call it a work around when it's not a bug. But the solution? Open a file manager.

---

I have a 1984 sharp FW-710 Font Writer:

[image]

The open dialogue looks like this:

[image]

This gets across the intentions of the open dialogue much better, in my opinion. Nowhere does it suggest you can delete any files - it clearly shows you need to enter the file name and it will open it. To delete, you have to close *Word Processor* and open *Utilities*.

While I wouldn't suggest Libre Office adopts this (for a start we have complex things like *Directories* and *Symbolic Links* that make it harder - and I doubt you remember the name of every file. But, when you see it like that, it shows clearly that it is an open dialogue and nothing else.

The save is the same:

[image]

This box doesn't look like you can remove anything, because a) you can't and b) you shouldn't be able to.

Maybe a couple of things were better 30 years ago?

> It's by design. Who wants a coffee machine (Libre Office) that also cooks pizza (Deletes Files)? Not me - I want my coffee machine (Libre Office) to make coffee (Open Files). My oven (File Manager) is there for pizza (Deleting Files).

Comment: @Tim: If I rename the file I have basically made two files out of one. This doesn't solve my problem: It makes it even worse. (BTW: It works flawlessly under Windows, starting the file manager for such a basic operation that has to do with the office files itself is just dada). I give the devs an F for shortsightedness and bad software design.

Comment: @empedokles I think I expained it pretty well - the file browse to open a file is there to... browse to open a file. At no point is deleting a requirement of Opening a file. I personally don't use the Windows renaming / deleting while looking for files. I don't think you could say a coffee machine has to be able to cook pizza, and then mark them down for it not being able to - what were you expecting to do when you open a file, other than open it? Windows has given people a weird expectation.

Comment: @Tim It's not weird. It's the only place one looks quite intuitively during his work hours at office files and it keeps the filelist small. It's a sign that many programmers don't actually use their own programs on a daily basis. If I have to interrupt my natural work routine in order to start a file browser just to get to the same point I already am in the opening dialogue that is just bad software design because it's not intuitive.

Comment: Please discuss this in a chat ;)